# Same code works on VS 2010 but not on 2005

Tags: asp.net, ajax, visual-studio-2010, visual-studio-2005

Right now I'm working on an ASP.NET web application that recquires Ajax. After reading [this tutorial](http://ajax.net-tutorials.com/basics/hello-world/) I tried running the following code in Visual Studio 2005, after adding the neccessary Controls by right-clicking the Toolbox and clicking "Choose Items...":

```
<%@ Page Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeFile="Default2.aspx.cs" Inherits="Default2" %>
<%@ Register Assembly="System.Web.Extensions, Version=3.5.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35"
    Namespace="System.Web.UI" TagPrefix="asp" %>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">

<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" >
<head runat="server">
    <title>Untitled Page</title>
</head>
<body>
    <form id="form1" runat="server">
        <asp:ScriptManager ID="ScriptManager1" runat="server"/>

        <asp:UpdatePanel ID="UpdatePanel1" runat="server">
            <ContentTemplate>
                <asp:Button ID="Button1" runat="server" Text="Button" OnClick="Button1_Click" />
                <asp:Label ID="Label1" runat="server" Text="Label"></asp:Label>
            </ContentTemplate>
        </asp:UpdatePanel>
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

---

```
protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Label1.Text += "<br/>" + DateTime.Now.ToString();
}
```

But for some reason, the page did not work with Ajax. When I clicked the button, the page refreshed and showed the label with updated values. I couldn't find anything wrong with this code, so I tried opening the same exact project in Visual Studio 2010 and running it. This time it worked! (the label was updated with the current date without refreshing the page)

What could prevent this code from working in Visual Studio 2005?

Thanks,
Itamar

Comment: If something is wrong with this question, please comment and let me know what it is.

Answer (score 0):

Might be your **UpdatePanel's UpdateMode** is set to `conditional` you have to specify a `trigger`.

Alternatively, you could define the property `ChildrenAsTriggers` to `true`.

Refer http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.updatepanel.updatemode.aspx

And  I don't find any register on top of your page?Have you buld it?If not try to add this

```
<%@ Register Assembly="AjaxControlToolkit" Namespace="AjaxControlToolkit" TagPrefix="asp" %>
```

Comment: Adding `ChildrenAsTriggers="True"` or `UpdateMode="Always"` didn't change anything.

Comment: Adding that register prevents it from building: _Error 1 Could not load file or assembly 'AjaxControlToolkit' or one of its dependencies. The system cannot find the file specified_ Do I need to install this toolkit?

Comment: you stated in your queston that you have done it by adding neccessary Controls by right-clicking the Toolbox and clicking "Choose Items...":If not try to do it by following this http://weblogs.asp.net/nannettethacker/archive/2008/02/07/ajax-control-tookit-installation-in-visual-web-developer.aspx

Comment: It's not related to VS2005 about installation of ajax control toolkit and once you done with that then try to do what I mentioned in my answer.

Comment: I added that piece of code after installing the toolkit, but nothing has changed, the page is still refreshed.

Comment: The same code you're trying to use can get from here try to download and find the errors you are implementing http://www.4guysfromrolla.com/articles/102407-1.aspx

Comment: it fails to load the System.Web.Extensions assembly.

Answer (score 0):

4GuysFromRolla states that Visual Studio 2005 is targeted at 2.0 .NET apps which may explain why v3.5 of the AJAX assembly won't work (http://www.4guysfromrolla.com/articles/112107-1.aspx). But Charles Young contradict this (http://geekswithblogs.net/cyoung/archive/2007/12/01/117279.aspx).

Answer (score 0):

I believe support for AJAX was limited in VS 2005. Try using the `ToolkitScriptManager` instead and see if that helps.

```
<cc1:ToolkitScriptManager ID="ToolkitScriptManager1" runat="server" EnablePartialRendering="true"></cc1:ToolkitScriptManager>
```

Comment: How do I add this `ToolkitScriptManager`? I can't find it in the .NET Framework Components list.

Comment: It's part of the AJAX Control Toolkit.

Comment: Okay, I installed the Toolkit and replaced the ScriptManager with ToolkitScriptManager.. But when running the code the page is still refreshed.